# Setting UIPicker showsSelectionIndicator to No does not work in ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uipickerview

Here is my Code : 
I have set showsSelectionIndicator to No. But it is still showing indicator in ios 7 but it is working fine in ios 6

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    pickerView.delegate=self;
    pickerView.dataSource=self;
    [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator=NO;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot customise the picker view’s selection indicator on iOS 7. The selection indicator is always shown, so the Shows Selection Indicator(showsSelectionIndicator) has no effect.

Check Apple's document [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPickerView.html)